# Question regarding Django - IIS - Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, iis

I've recently built my first real web app for 'work' using Django. I'm using Postgres for my backend database. I'm also hosting my app and database on the same Windows 2019 server. IIS is the tool that I'm using to host my web app.

Essentially what my issue is when I have my website live in production, my export count in the csv doesn't match my filtered records count in my search. It works sometimes but usually when the row count is smaller. The issue usually happens if the row count is in the tens of thousands (shown in screenshot).

My hunch is that it's due to some network setting somewhere in IIS but i could be wrong. Everything works perfectly when I'm just running on localhost. I'm not too familiar on what database or IIS settings should be set to allow for optimal performance.

I have 16 GB of ram on my server and a 8 core processor so i don't think that's the issue but i could be wrong. My database is like 8 million some rows so there is definitely a lot of data to go through.

Below is code of my export_to_csv view as well. I'm using a StreamingHttpResponse which is what Django recommends. Thank you all in advance! I'm pretty stumped and could use any help i could get.

[image]

```
class Echo(object):
    """An object that implements just the write method of the file-like
    interface.
    """
    def write(self, value):
        """Write the value by returning it, instead of storing in a buffer."""
        return value

def export_to_csv(request):
    all_objects = DeviceVulns.objects.all()
    url = request.GET.get('filter_url')
    query = urlsplit(url).query
    params = dict(parse_qs(query))
    params_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in params.items()}
    #print(params_dict)
    filter = DeviceVulnsFilter(params_dict,queryset=all_objects).qs
    filter_list = list(filter.values_list())
    #insert headers into beginning of list
    filter_list[:0] = [['ID','Hostname', 'IP Address', 'OS_Name', 'Vuln Title','CVSS Score','Vuln Earliest Found Date On Asset','Vuln Exploitable?','Vuln Exploit Skill Level']]
    pseudo_buffer = Echo()
    writer = csv.writer(pseudo_buffer)
    response = StreamingHttpResponse((writer.writerow(
        [item[1], item[2], item[3],
         item[4], item[5],item[6],item[7],item[8]]) for item in filter_list),
                                     content_type="text/csv")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="filtered-data.csv"'
    return response
```

Comment: How many records are you facing? If the function works on a smaller scale, try to submit the filter and refresh the page a few minutes later. That might work. Otherwise, make sure all tests are passed and the webserver can show the filtered data in the shell properly, so then try implementing [indexing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#indexes) in your model.

Comment: Have you thought that it may be caused by length of url? I see that you append the filter criteria to the url as a query string, which results in a very long url. IIS will give a clear status code indicating that the URL is too long, but there is still an unknowable risk of a long URL that meets the requirements. I think you can try to optimize the URL to reduce the length of the query string.